# How can I use these peaches in a box cake mix?

Tags: baking, peaches

I have a box of Super Moist cake mix, butter recipe Yellow.  It calls for 1 cup of water, 1/3 cup butter, softened, and 3 eggs. I also have a 15 ounce can of Sliced peaches. How can I combine these for cupcakes?

We are moving in a month and I'd rather find a way to eat the peaches than m move them.  Lol

Comment: Could that cake mix be used to make a cobbler crust instead?

Comment: don't know about the cupcakes, but do a search on your favorite search engine for "dump cake" + peaches.

Comment: The person I bake for its finicky and doesn't like what he calls "messy" Food. That's why I'm trying for cupcakes.

Comment: Joe, it seems those dump cake recipes all want about 29 or 30 ounces of peaches.  So I guess I'm trying to figure out how to substitute the peaches and the Juice for the water Eggs

Answer (score 2):

I bet you can puree some peaches and their juice to use in place of the butter and water, respectively. Although, the texture might be better if you only replace half of the butter.  I wouldn't recommend replacing the eggs with peaches because that would make the cake quite crumbly.  Note that the peaches can make the cake a lot sweeter, especially if they're canned in heavy syrup.

Perhaps a better use would be to turn the peaches into an ice cream or sorbet to serve with the cake.  You could also add a small amount of peach to some butter and powdered sugar to make a buttercream frosting for the cake.

Comment: Those are great ideas, moog. I wish I realized I could lose most of the butter but here's what I did.

Comment: I used 2 Eggs, 1 stick of butter, the entire contents of the can (was in juice) and 1 teaspoon baking powder, plus the cake mix. Combined them and it turned out quite good. Not too sweet with a light fluffy texture. (beat 5 minutes at medium speed) .

Comment: @Laura0703, I'm glad that worked out so well.  Thanks for sharing the recipe you ended up using.  I'm tempted to try that same approach with a can of pears and a few pecans. :-)  What inspired you to add the extra baking powder?

Comment: I added the baking powder because I was dropping an egg and I thought it would need the lift to keep it light.  It was quite sweet and moist (without being too moist) but my crowd goes for sweer.  Mine were in juice.  Definitely cut down on the butter from a whole stick.

Answer (score 1):

You could just chop the peaches use the canned juice instead of the wter called for in the directions, or use the canned juice as a glaze after cakes are done or add to the frosting.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers above. One more option: cobbler:

1 Melt all the butter in a large glass pie plate or a glass lasagna pan.
2. Distribute peaches in pan
3.Mix the cake batter (w/out the butter) with some juice as liquid (1/2 cup more or less)
4. Pour batter over do not mix.
5. Bake in preheated 375f 40 - 45min nicely browned and bubbly

Cinn on top nice